# Anyone have more details on a XBox 360 Console History Export Project?

Tags: facebook, xna, xbox360, xbox

Recently, at the Charlotte 2009 Code Camp someone was telling me about a project/product that would export the history of a XBox 360 Console and then create some kind of diary or journal for the XBox.

He didn't really know the details, but he thought it would take the Xbox Console history and then convert it into one of the social networking sites like FaceBook.

So it might look like this:

Chris played "Halo Wars" for 3 hours today... more specific details like score etc.

I didn't see Chris at all today. Hope he stops by soon.

Chris played "Galaxy Wars" for 2 hours today... again even more details.

I don't know for sure it would make it FaceBook content. It could have been a blog, or Twitter, or anything else.

I thought it was a great idea, and I was wanting to check it out, and hoping that it is open source because then I have some ideas of my own.

Either way first I need to find it. And so far all my searching has been for vain.

If you know any more details please share, because I'm sure there are others who are curious now too. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like what [the 360 voice](http://360voice.gamerdna.com/) is doing?